# Return Dictionary object in an Array by searching for a certain value

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

I've got an array with dictionaries in it. Like this:

```
[{date:1991, value: 78}, {date:1992, value: 102}, {date:1993, value: 277}]
```

What's a good way to search for the object with date:1991 and return the value?

Comment: ues a `for` or `while` loop

Answer (score 6):

Using `filter()` of method, you can do it as,

```js
const dict = [ {date:1991, value: 78}, 
              {date:1992, value: 102}, 
              {date:1993, value: 277} ]

console.log(dict.filter(obj => obj.date === 1991))
```

---

You could also use a user defined function for doing the same as you requested, if you want answer in simple `for` and `if` loops.

```js
var dict = [{date:1991, value: 78}, {date:1992, value: 102}, {date:1993, value: 277}]

function search_obj(dict, year) {
  for (obj of dict) {
    if (obj.date === year) {
      return obj
    }
  }
}

console.log(search_obj(dict, 1991))
```

Comment: this seems like alot of work compared to the other answers.

Comment: you can use the first method using ES6 and ```filter()``` method, which gives you solution in a single line.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method.

```js
var data = [{
    date: 1991,
    value: 78
  }, {
    date: 1992,
    value: 102
  }, {
    date: 1993,
    value: 277
  }],
  date = 1991;

console.log(
  (data.find(function(v) {
    return v.date == date;
  }) || {}).value
)
```

For older browser check [polyfill option of find method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Polyfill).

Comment: he said return the value not object

Comment: IE not support 'array#find'

Comment: value means `value`  property in object

Comment: @azad :  added polyfill option

Comment: @Mahi :  it can be accessed later using dot notation

Answer (score 1):

create your own search function.

```
var arr = [{date:1991, value: 78}, {date:1992, value: 102}, {date:1993, value: 277}];

function searchFn(searchDate){

    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        if(arr[i] == searchDate)
            return arr[i];
}

//search
searchFn(1991);//{date:1991, value: 78}
searchFn(1992);//{date:1992, value: 102}
```

Answer (score 0):

simply use forEach method .

```js
var arr=[{date:1991, value: 78}, {date:1992, value: 102}, {date:1993, value: 277},{date:1991, value: 79}];
var v=1991,ans=[];

arr.forEach(function(a){
if(a.date==v)
   ans.push(a.value);
});
console.log(ans);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple filter statement:

```js
var data = [{date:1991, value: 78}, {date:1992, value: 102}, {date:1993, value: 277}]
var result = data.filter(x => x.date == 1991)
console.log(result)
```

Comment: If you want a list of values you can also use map: `result = result.map(x => x.value)`. And If you're sure there is only one element, then append [0] to get it.